# Laravel - Yajra Datatable sorting and searching for relationship column

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am struggling to make sorting and searching for working on the relationship columns in Laravel/[Yajra Datatables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships).

I have a `Metro` model that has a relationship with `Station`. Here is my code.

## metros table columns

```
id, name, number, origin_id, destination_id, created_at, updated_at
```

## stations table columns

```
id, name, code, info, photo, created_at, updated_at
```

## Metro Model

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function origin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class, 'origin_id');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function destination()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class, 'destination_id');
}
```

## MetroController JSON

```
/**
 * DataTable json data request
 *
 * @param \App\Metro $metro
 *
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function jsonData(Metro $metro)
{
    return DataTables::of($metro::select('id', 'name', 'number', 'origin_id', 'destination_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'))
                     ->addColumn('action', function ($metro) {

                         $show    = route('admin.metros.show', $metro);
                         $edit    = route('admin.metros.edit', $metro);
                         $destroy = route('admin.metros.destroy', $metro);
                         $attr    = 'onclick=metroDelete(' . $metro->id . ')';

                         return view('admin.components.action', compact([
                             'show',
                             'edit',
                             'destroy',
                             'attr',
                         ]));

                     })
                     ->editColumn('origin_id', function ($metro) {
                         return '<a href="'.route('admin.stations.show', $metro->origin->id).'">' . $metro->origin->name . '</a>';
                     })
                     ->editColumn('destination_id', function ($metro) {
                         return '<a href="'.route('admin.stations.show', $metro->destination->id).'">' . $metro->destination->name . '</a>';
                     })
                     ->editColumn('created_at', function ($metro) {
                         return $metro->created_at->diffForHumans();
                     })
                     ->escapeColumns([])
                     ->make(TRUE);
}
```

## View - Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let metroDataTable = $('#metroDataTable');

    metroDataTable.DataTable({
        serverSide  : true,
        processing  : true,
        autoWidth   : false,
        ajax        : '{!! route('admin.metros.json') !!}',
        lengthMenu  : [[25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [25, 50, 75, 100, "All"]],
        columns     : [
            {data: 'id', name: '{{__('admin.metro.id')}}', width: '50px'},
            {data: 'name', name: '{{__('admin.metro.name')}}', width: '100px'},
            {data: 'number', name: '{{__('admin.metro.number')}}', width: '100px'},
            {data: 'origin_id', name: '{{__('admin.metro.origin')}}', width: '200px'},
            {data: 'destination_id', name: '{{__('admin.metro.destination')}}', width: '200px'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {
                data      : 'action',
                name      : '{{__('admin.action')}}',
                orderable : false,
                searchable: false,
                className : 'text-center'
            },
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var input  = document.createElement("input");
                $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                    });
            });
        }

    }); // end of DataTables

}); // end of jQuery Document
```

When I try to sort the `Origin` or `Destination` column or search for the column it is giving me the following error.

[image]

> **Question:**
>
> How can I make 'origin`and`destination` columns sortable and searchable?

Comment: Why are you translating the `name` in the dataTables `columns` option? This is only used by the dataTable API so there should be no need to translate it. Try changing `name: '{{__('admin.metro.origin_id')}}'` to `name: 'origin_id'`.

Comment: I see. So I misunderstood a bit. Thanks to clarify it. Appreciate :)

Comment: Okay cool, that resolved the error issue but it is not shorting by station name but by the id which I store into `metros` table.

Comment: You can read more about relationship sorting / filtering [here](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships).  You would have to eager load the relationship `$metro::with('origin')` and then you could change the name to `name: 'origin.name'`

Comment: @Remul I am not yet an expert in Laravel so I follow that one before I post a query here. The problem I got following the guide is the `map` function. `return $user->posts->map(function($post) ...`. Giving me something like function not found kind of error. So do I have to write `map` function somewhere in my Controller? Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: No you don't need that, it is only there to display all posts that the user has, it is not needed for sorting / filtering. I will add an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to translate the `name` in the `columns` option, this value is only used by the dataTables API, so you should not translate it:

Change

```
{data: 'origin_id', name: '{{__('admin.metro.origin')}}', width: '200px'},
```

to

```
// If data and name are the same you can remove the name altogether
{data: 'origin_id', width: '200px'},
```

In order to allow filtering / sorting on the origin name you would have to do the following.

Eager load the relationship in your controller:

```
// Not sure why are passing a model instance here
return DataTables::of($metro::with('origin', 'destination')

// This should be the same but in my opinion cleaner
return DataTables::of(Metro::with('origin', 'destination')
```

Change the name attribute in the columns option:

```
{data: 'origin_id', name: 'origin.name', width: '200px'},
```

You can read more about relationships for dataTables [here](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships).

Comment: You are a genius. The problem is solved in just a few lines. Thanka a lot.  One more thing to learn what if I want to get specific fields from the table? As now I have replaced `::of` with `::with`?

Comment: You should not replace `::of` with `::with`. I don't understand why you are passing a model instance in the first place. It should be something like `DataTables::of(Metro::with('origin', 'destination')->select('your columns'));`

Comment: Cool... got it. Thanks for clarifying it.